# Parameterization of a triangle in $\mathbb R^3$ (edge and surface)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Let $S$ be a triangle with vertices at A=$(1,2,0)$, B=$(2,3,2)$, and C=$(0,0,4)$. Find a parametrization of the triangle and its contour.

I have set up the parametric equations for each edge

$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$-$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$

first edge: $r_1(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}  + t\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1+t \\ 2+t \\ 0+2t\end{pmatrix}$

likewise for the others

$r_2(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 2-2t \\ 3-3t \\ 2+2t\end{pmatrix}$

$r_3(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 0+t \\ 0+2t \\ 0-4t\end{pmatrix}$

for each $t \in [0,1]$

What can I do now? How to put them together, and how to get the parametrization of the whole surface and not only the edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is all you need to do for the edges. You could parametrize so you could go from $0 \leq t \leq 1, 2 \leq t \leq 2, 2 \leq t \leq 3$.

$r_1(t)= (1, 2, 0) + (1, 1, 2)t = (1 + t, 2 + t, 2t) \,$ for $( 0 \leq t \leq 1)$

$r_2(t)= (2, 3, 2) + (-2, -3, 2) (t-1) = (4-2t, 6-3t, 2t) \,$ for $( 1 \leq t \leq 2)$

$r_3(t)= (0, 0, 4) + (1, 2, -4) (t-2) = (-2 + t, -4 + 2t, 12-4t) \,$ for $( 2 \leq t \leq 3)$

Now if you have to parametrize the surface, find the equation of the plane it is on. First take two directional vectors you found above and do a cross product to find the normal vector to the plane-

$(-2, -3, 2) \times (1, 1, 2) = (-8, 6, 1)$

Take any point on the surface say $(0, 0, 4)$ then we have,

$ -8(x-0) + 6(y-0) + (z-4) = 0$

Parametrization of the surface of the plane the given triangle is on,

$ \,z = 4 + 8x - 6y$

EDIT:

On the parametrization that you asked,

If you take parametrization of two of your edges, $r_1(s) = (1 + s, 2 + s, 2s) \,(0 \leq s \leq 1)$

$r_2(t) = (2 - 2t, 3 - 3t, 2 + 2t) \,(0 \leq t \leq 1)$

You can combine these two to parametrize your triangle.

$r(s, t) = (1 + s - 2t, 2 + s - 3t, 2s + 2t) \, \, (0 \leq s, t \leq 1)$

If you take cross product $r_t \times r_s$, you will get the normal vector $(-8, 6, 1)$ which is what I used for other parametrization.

Comment: Thank you very much. You know what I tried to do was something similar to this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218336/parameterization-of-a-triangle-in-mathbb-r3 with $r(s,t)=$. But I do not know how to start.

Comment: What we have here is the parametrization of the edges and the plane with boundary as vertices. Do you want me to show what the parametrization would be in the way you were trying to get to?

Comment: Oh yes that would be perfect. Because in the other thread it was only said that it was done with a software. I wanted to know how to do it by hand.

Comment: Thank you soo much! Unfortunately I can only upvote once :) The parameterization of the plane could I write it as (s,t, 4+8s-6t) ? what would the boundaries be here for s and t?

Comment: In the previous one, we are using normal vector to the plane and a point in the plane. In this parametrization, we are using two vectors in the plane (not parallel to each other) and a point in the plane. Both represent the same plane but in different ways and we set bounds accordingly to represent our triangle.

Comment: thank you for your help:)