# Using triple integration for the area of a triangle

Tags: calculus, integration

For practice I am trying to use the standard definition of volume for a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ given by:

$$vol(X) := \int_X dx_1 \ \ldots \ dx_n$$

to compute the area of the triangle spanned by the points $(0,0,1), (0,2,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. the standard area of this triangle, ***NOT*** the area of its projection to the $xy$-plane. (The result should be $1.22$.)

The triangle lies in the plane $x-y-2z = -2$. Since it furthermore holds $0 \le z \le 1$, $y=x-2z+2$ and for $x = 0$ holds $y = 2z$  I tried

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{2z} \int_0^{x - 2 z + 2} dy dx dz \approx 1.3333$$

, which is false. I suspect I am making some error with the boundaries of the integrals, but I am not sure where. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the area of the triangle or the volume under it to the plane, let's say $z=0$?

Comment: ..and, obviously $(1,1,1)$ doesn't lie on $x=z-1$.

Comment: @zkutch: I edited my question to clarify and fixed the equation of the plane.

Comment: There is clearly an error with the boundaries (assuming you wanted the boundaries to integrate only on the surface of the triangle), but the fundamental error is using a triple integral for area. If you were to repair the boundaries you would get a result of zero, because a triple integral used in this way computes volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know from where you got your formula, but I have even dimensional doubt in it, because area is second power of length, while triple integral gives third power.

Now back to work. One way how to calculate area of triangle in space is imagine it as some surface and then use well known formula for [area of surface for function](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/surfacearea.aspx)
$$\iint\limits_{G}\sqrt{1+(z'_x)^2+(z'_y)^2}dxdy$$
where $G$ is projection on $Oxy$ plane.

In your case we obtain
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{x}^{2-x}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}dxdy=\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\approx 1.224744$$

Second way I see to map your triangle onto $Oxy$ plane and calculate it using the usual double integral, taking into account the Jacobian of the transformation, which I will leave as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, [parameterize](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218431/) and integrate along $X$; for $(u,v)\in[0,1]^2$, let

$$\begin{align*}
\vec r(u,v) &= (1-v)(1,1,1) + v[(1-u)(0,0,1) + u(0,2,0)]\\
&= (1-v, 1-v+2uv, 1-uv)
\end{align*}$$

Get the normal vector and its magnitude:

$$\vec n = \frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial v} = (-v,v,2v) \implies \|\vec n\| = \sqrt6 \, \lvert v\rvert$$

The subsequent [surface integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_scalar_fields) for the area is trivial.